# Blob is sent via windows.open, but not via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, webrtc, video-capture, video.js

I'm using the RecordRTC to record a video and then save it on the server.

I have a problem. With the classic method pushed by the author, I can send the video, it's working:

```
    xhr('temoignages/save.php', formData, function (fName) {
            window.open(location.href + fName);
        });

        function xhr(url, data, callback) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    callback(location.href + request.responseText);
                }
            };
            request.open('POST', url);
            request.send(data);
        }
```

But I don't like the fact that it is opening a new windows. It doesn't work all the time because  of the popup blocker.

So I changed it to this :

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'temoignages/save.php',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(data) {
               console.log(data);
        });
```

But it's not working.
I get this in the console:

```
        Initialized recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder for output-type: video
            started recording!
            Stopped recording video stream.
            Recorder state changed: stopped
            video/webm -> 46.8 KB
            finished recording:  {video: Blob(46849)}
            Invalid temp_name: 
            XHR finished loading: POST ".../save.php".
```

And when I use the exact same code to send an mp3 file, it's working with both methods. What Am I missing ?

Comment: what happens when you send the mp3 then? What constitutes "working"? The original code opens a window with a URL based on data from the response. Your new code simply logs that response data to the console instead, it will not attempt to open anything. Are you saying it doesn't log the value? What response (status and content) do you get from the ajax call? I notice your code doesn't handle AJAX errors (e.g. using a .fail() callback).

Comment: Thanks for you answer !
My code ask my file save.php to save the media locally.
That's what constitutes working. The mp3 is saved, but the mp4 doesn't want to save. It's not sent via ajax.

Comment: Ok so if the server is not receiving the file, you need to find out what went wrong. Like I said, what response (status and content) do you get from the ajax call?

Comment: I have done more testing. And it's working perfectly on firefox. Ajax doesn't send only on chrome. Does that help you? Other than that, the response is good on firefox : "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="video-blob"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: video/webm"

Comment: If you wanna try on your end: https://les-nouveaux-hommes.fr/temoignage.php

Comment: It helps a bit. But what happens instead on Chrome, when it fails? Like I said, report the status code and response given by the request. Or, if the request is not executed, what happens instead? Some console error maybe? Do you understand how to find that information? Thanks for the link to the site, but not being a French-speaker I have no idea what to do or which part I am supposed to use which would be relevant to your question, sorry. Perhaps you can tell me exactly what to click on to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry about that.
Just click on "Un témoignage vidéo", and then use the black box to use the video recording script with the console open. No need to validate the form or anything else, just use the record button.